# Exception thrown when saving excel file

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I wrote up a method that takes all the cells from a DataGridView and copies them to an Excel workbook.

It all works fine and dandy, up until I get to the part where I actually save it.

Here is the code that saves it:

```
        //Saves the Workbook to the specified path
        excelWorkbook.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(pathToSave);
        excelWorkbook.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;

        //Close the workbook
        excelWorkbook.Quit();
```

And the exception being thrown:

```
Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\TheGateKeeper\Desktop\New folder'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
```

This is the first time I am working with this class, so I may have messed something up.

Also as a sidenote, what does:

```
 excelWorkbook.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
```

do?

Thanks.

Comment: 'C:\Users\TheGateKeeper\Desktop\New folder' is directory. How you set excel filename?

Comment: Doh! To what extension does the interlop class save as?

Comment: 1. What are value of variable pathToSave? 2. Are directory ''C:\Users\TheGateKeeper\Desktop\New folder' exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the argument of the **SaveCopyAs** method to path of the excel file including extension.

eg. `C:\Users\TheGateKeeper\Desktop\TestFile.xls`.

The extension specifies the format of the workbook, eg .xls (2003 and <), .,xlsx (2007 +)

For your side note, setting Saved to true flags the content as saved it doesn't actually write it to disk.

> To open a workbook file, use the Open method.
>
> To mark a workbook as saved without writing it to a disk, set its
>   Saved property to True.
>
> The first time you save a workbook, use the SaveAs method to specify a
>   name for the file.

Source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.save%28v=office.11%29.aspx)